# not able to perform any operation on existing table in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, user-controls, public

I have created RO user and it's working fine but only thing is that it is not able to perform any operation on already created table.
I am using below query:

```
CREATE ROLE rw LOGIN PASSWORD '123';
GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE test to rw;
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA public TO rw;
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO rw;
GRANT SELECT ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA public TO rw;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA public GRANT SELECT ON tables TO PUBLIC;
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO PUBLIC;
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO PUBLIC;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE "test" to rw;
```

This table is created before RW user creation:

```
insert into mobile(device_name,model_no) values('poco','4');
```

getting below error:
ERROR:  permission denied for table mobile
SQL state: 42501

need suggestion...

Comment: Without example(s) of the operation(s) you are doing and the result, error or otherwise this can't be answered. Add the preceding as an update to your question.

Comment: I am getting permission denied:ERROR:  permission denied for table mobile
SQL state: 42501

Comment: Is table `mobile` in the database and schema you show above? Also include the actual command you are running.  Please add this information and your previous comment to your question. This helps others looking to provide an answer by not having to run through all the comments to get useful information.

Comment: Added the details .. I need query which allow the newly created user to perform all operation on already created table,

Comment: Then you will have specifically `GRANT` those privileges to the user. Not quite what you are trying to achieve, but I would take a look at [DEFAULT PRIVILEGES](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-alterdefaultprivileges.html)

Comment: Some possibilities: 1) you are running the `GRANT`s in a different database 2) you are running the `GRANT`s in a transaction that is then rolled back.

Comment: Issue fixed after running below query:GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO rw;

Comment: Except now  role `rw` is no longer read only.